# Computing a weighted Jaccard similarity index for point clouds with scikit-learn

Tags: python, similarity, scikit-learn

I would like to use the Jaccard Similarity Index to compute the overlap between to point clouds, following [Brede et al. 2022](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rse.2022.113180). Here, they voxelise a point cloud and then compute the intersection and union of voxels.

Here is a 2D dummy dataset

```
# dummy random data
X = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(1000, 2)), columns=['x', 'y'])
X.loc[:, 'D'] = 0 # dataset 1
Y = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=1, size=(1000, 2)), columns=['x', 'y'])
Y.loc[:, 'D'] = 1 # dataset 2 

df = pd.concat([X, Y]) 

# voxelise into arbitrary voxels 
df.loc[:, 'xx'] = (df.x // 2)
df.loc[:, 'yy'] = (df.y // 2)

# map unique value to each voxel
df.loc[:, 'VX'] = df.apply(lambda row: struct.pack('i', int(row.xx)) + struct.pack('i', int(row.yy)), axis=1)

# plot
MAP = {vx:i for i, vx in enumerate(df.VX.unique())}
df.loc[:, 'class'] = df.VX.map(MAP)
df.plot.scatter('x', 'y', c='D', cmap='viridis')
```

Now I would like to add weights where number of points per voxel is divided by maximum number of points in a voxel for each point cloud.

```
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score

def J_weights(df):
    
    # calculate weights by counting number of points
    # in each voxel. Divide by maximum so that datasets
    # of different densities can be compared
    weights = df.groupby('VX').x.count()
    weights /= weights.max()
    return weights.to_dict()

def J_SCORE(MAN, AUT, weights=False):
    
    VX = list(set(MAN.VX.unique().tolist() + AUT.VX.unique().tolist()))
    # binary identifier where voxels have >0 points in each
    MAN.loc[:, 'a'] = 1
    AUT.loc[:, 'a'] = 1
    
    # one dataframe with both datasets so that 
    # empty voxels are easier to identify 
    X = pd.DataFrame()
    X.loc[:, 'VX'] = VX # all occupied voxels across datasets

    # map which voxels are occupied
    X.loc[:, 'MAN'] = X.VX.map(dict(MAN[['VX', 'a']].values))
    X.loc[:, 'AUT'] = X.VX.map(dict(AUT[['VX', 'a']].values))
    X.loc[:, ['MAN', 'AUT']] = X[['MAN', 'AUT']].fillna(0) # fill empty voxels with a 0

    # calculate weights using the above function
    X.loc[:, 'M_W'] = X.VX.map(J_weights(MAN))
    X.loc[:, 'A_W'] = X.VX.map(J_weights(AUT))
    X.loc[:, ['A_W', 'M_W']] = X[['A_W', 'M_W']].fillna(0)

    # determine heaviest weight for each voxel
    X.loc[:, 'W'] = X[['M_W', 'A_W']].max(axis=1)

    # calculate jaccard index with weights
    return jaccard_score(X.MAN.values, X.AUT.values, 
                         sample_weight=X.W.values if weights else np.ones(len(X)))

J_SCORE(df.loc[df.D == 0], df.loc[df.D == 1], weights=True)
```

I am using the [sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html)

For the above example, if I compute an unweighted Jaccard Similarity Index (`weights=False` in the above) I get a value of ~0.4 and if I calculated a weighted score I get a value of ~0.8. I understand this as 40% of occupied voxels are shared and 80% of points share the same voxels. Obviously these values are dependent on voxel size.

My questions are:

(1) would the weighted approach be a valid method for comparing the space occupied by point clouds and

(2) how do weights in this (sklearn implementation) context relate to [Weighted Jaccard similarity and distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index#Weighted_Jaccard_similarity_and_distance) which the equation for is below.

[image: weighted Jaccard Index]

For example, taking X from the above function

```
X.loc[:, 'MX'] = X[['M_W', 'A_W']].max(axis=1)
X.loc[:, 'MN'] = X[['M_W', 'A_W']].min(axis=1)

X.MN.sum() / X.MX.sum()
```

Returns a value of ~20%